# How to Change LightType for Nvidia's PCSS Soft Shadows In Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I referred to https://github.com/TheMasonX/UnityPCSS

Currently this implementation is only directional light. However, in Current Limitations, I need to directly overriding UnityShadowLibrary.cginc to use spot or point light, but I do not know what to do.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that asset is limited to directional lights only. If you'd like something similar for point and spotlights, I highly recommend NGSS: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/vfx/shaders/next-gen-soft-shadows-79454.

It includes both PCSS and PCF filters.